# Should we merge the meta tags [licensing] and [license]?

Tags: discussion, meta-tags, licensing

There are two meta tags, [license](/questions/tagged/license) (13 questions tagged) and [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) (54 questions tagged), that seem like they cover the same topic. <strike>Neither one has a tag wiki, but they both appear to be about the license on site content.</strike> I've proposed tag wikis for each of these.

Some of the questions seem to be along the lines of "Can I ask about licensing on Stack Overflow?", which I don't think is an appropriate reason to use/have such a tag. "(Where) can I ask this" type questions shouldn't be tagged based on the question in question, or we would have a whole lot of one-off tags specific to "Are XYZ questions allowed?".

These two tags should be merged/synonymized, or perhaps merged with a new tag with a clearer name (perhaps [stack-exchange-content-license](/questions/tagged/stack-exchange-content-license)?).